# how to disable enable button using in listview checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am creating checkbox listview following by

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {

if (product.get(i).get("check_box_enable").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
     Log.d("Values true", "" + Order_list.get(i));
 check_to_answer.setEnabled(true);
        check_to_answer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_color)      );
        }
 else{
check_to_answer.setEnabled(false);
}
    }
```

its work but for loop is check 1st is false `check_to_answer.setEnabled(true);`execute. but array list last values true execute `check_to_answer.setEnabled(false);`

now i want arraylist checkbox is get "false" button is enabled. or "true" get button is disabled how to write the condition help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add boolean flag before loop and set it to true if condition is met.

```
boolean isEnabled = false;

for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {
    if (product.get(i).get("check_box_enable").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
         isEnabled = true;
         break;
    }
}

check_to_answer.setEnabled(isEnabled);

if (isEnabled) {
    check_to_answer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_color));
} else {
    // ...
}
```